# How do we mute the <censored> Facebook app?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, notifications, facebook

IOS 12.1.4 (16D57) on iPhone MG5D2LL/A

With Facebook not allowed to give any notifications except badges, …

the sound turned off for Facebook in notification settings, …

notifications turned off in the Facebook settings, …

keyboard clicks turned off, …

and volume turned completely off with the iPhone volume buttons, …

when my wife posts something in the Facebook app, her iPhone makes a click that annoys her.

How can we make it stop?

Comment: I don’t use the app but one thing I also noticed is that the speech to text button on the keyboard makes sound even if everything is on silent mode. I assumed that it’s necessary as it is taking private information directly for processing.

Comment: Did you put the phone in silent mode? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208353

Comment: No, I wrote, "volume turned completely off with the iPhone _volume_ buttons," which unlike the badly misnamed "silent mode" is supposed to mute _all_ sounds.